# Redirect STDOUT of a RUN command in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, stdout

I need to concatenate two files together during a Docker build session. The concatenated file will then be accessed within container in a subsequent step.

When I try to use this in a Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./a /tmp
COPY ./b /tmp
RUN ["ls", "/tmp"]
RUN ["cat", "/tmp/a", "/tmp/b", ">/tmp/c"]
RUN ["ls", "/tmp"]
```

and then try to build the container I get this error:

```
Step 3/13 : COPY ./a /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 253aad0eae1a
Step 4/13 : COPY ./b /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0f86ea5731bf
Step 5/13 : RUN ["ls", "/tmp"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9aae6a9e657
Step 6/13 : RUN ["cat", "/tmp/a", "/tmp/b", ">/tmp/c"]
 ---> Running in 3aed3ca981ab
Tue Oct  5 16:29:32 EDT 2021
Tue Oct  5 16:29:33 EDT 2021
cat: >/tmp/c: No such file or directory
The command 'cat /tmp/a /tmp/b >/tmp/c' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How do I redirect STDOUT with the RUN command?

Is there another command I can use that accepts the output filename as a parameter?

I know I can create a small script and add that to the container and then run that script, but I was hoping to be able to do this within the Dockerfile.

Comment: "small script" ... that's a small *shell* script. The thing that knows what to do with `>` is a shell, which you explicitly bypassed with the json/exec syntax to RUN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `RUN` with the `exec` from
`RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"]`
where shell features like expanding variables, sub commands, piping output, chaining commands together won't work, use `RUN` in `shell` form enter the command as one string `RUN <command>`

```
COPY ./a /tmp
COPY ./b /tmp
RUN ls /tmp
RUN cat /tmp/a /tmp/b > /tmp/c
RUN ls /tmp
```

Comment: This is correct, but can you explain why; what's different from the original Dockerfile, and why does it make a difference?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried a variation of your solution:

 RUN "cat /tmp/a /tmp/b > /tmp/c"

but that resulted in:

/bin/sh: 1: cat /tmp/a /tmp/b > /tmp/c: not found

I didn't realize that the double quotes resulted in the entire line being treated as a single command.